# Week of year is not correctly shown

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-timeindex

I have a time frame data from 2005 uptil now. While converting date to week, it is not converting week correctly. Showing week 0 at start of year e.g. 2008/01/01 is indicated by week 0.

I first import excel file into pandas df and parse date column.

```
df = pd.read_excel('graph.xls',
                 parse_dates=['date'])
```

Datatype of date column is:

```
df['date'].dtypes
```

Output is `dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Then i convert date to week using:

```
df['Week'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%U')
df.head()
```

This shows week at start of year say 2007/01/01 to be 0 instead of 1.

Comment: can you indicate why you think this is not right?

Comment: (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html "All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.")

Comment: generally, week starts from 1 and ends at 52 in calendar year. How can we change it from 0 to 1?

Comment: "generally, week starts from 1 and ends at 52 in calendar year." not quite. there isn't a integer number of weeks in a year, so there is going to be 53 numbers. week numbering are confusing anyway. (also are you sure you want to count weeks starting from a Sunday?)

Comment: Since we agree that there si nothing wrong with the code, and that the question actually originates from a preference for numbering starting at 1 instead of 0, should we not close the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Week'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%U').astype('float64') + 1
```